# Why does Haxe print MySQL datestamp outside of a for loop but not inside?

Tags: mysql, haxe

```
cnx.request("
    INSERT INTO 
    sensorinput 
       (node_id, temperature, humidity, dateAdded) 
    VALUES 
       (1, 2200, 7800, '1998-12-12 23:12:59')");

var date = cnx.request("
    SELECT dateAdded 
    FROM 
      sensorinput 
    WHERE id=1
 ");
 Lib.println(date.getResult(0));
```

Works just fine. Prints the `'1998-12-12 23:12:59'` from MySQL database without any problems. However if I try to print all timestamps like this:

```
var date = cnx.request("SELECT dateAdded FROM sensorinput");
for(r in date)
{
  Lib.println(date.getResult(0));
}
```

It will just print ' null '.

Any ideas how to print all the timestamps from sensorinput?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var date = cnx.request("SELECT dateAdded FROM sensorinput");
for(r in date)
{
  Lib.println(r.dateAdded);
}
```

Comment: With that it gives output of 'Date Date Date... Date' depending on how many rows do I have in database.

Comment: @tsalmela perhaps you need `Lib.println(r.dateAdded.toString())`, depending on the target you're using..